# How to add modal inside cellrenderer in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

```
cellRenderer: (params) => {
  var eDiv = document.createElement('div');
  eDiv.innerHTML = '<b><div style="overflow:unset"><div class="btn-group btn-group-sm"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true"><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></button></div></div></b>';
  var eButton = eDiv.querySelectorAll(".icon")[0];
  eButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    alert("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa")
  });

  return eDiv;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use ReactDom.createPortal API

It is well explained in react docs

https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html

Also, there is a nice implementation shown here
https://medium.com/@imranhsayed/create-modal-in-react-using-portal-48b3662a28b9

Comment: I want to create a modal in side cell renderer using ag grid(react 15.x v)